# SELECT query working on every column except "title"

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have some data in a database which I want to display on a website. I want to query the storename_history table to get all data where the title contains what the user searches (in this instance the word Pink.)

My database table looks like this:

| productId | title | price | isAvailable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123DEF | Pink | 0.45 | 1 |

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM storename_history WHERE title = "%Pink%"
```

This query works with every column except for title. How's this possible?

It does not give an error: it just finds nothing.

Comment: Can you add the error here

Comment: What kind of condition it is ? `title = 'Pink'` or `title LIKE '%Pink%'`

Comment: Your query does not work with any column.

Comment: @MUGABA Added the info, sorry! I don't receive an error, it just doesn't return anything.

Comment: @forpas it actually does, I wouldn't say so otherwise.

Comment: How does it work? Do you have values in your columns equal to "%Pink%"?

Comment: @kadet  I used title = 'Pink' however using LIKE was the solution to this problem.

Comment: @forpas Nope, those that contain strings are all 1 "word" hence why those did work. using LIKE was the solution in this case

Comment: Then *This query works with every column* is misleading, isn't it?

Comment: It can work for you in some cases, only with your original edit of the post, where you had `WHERE title = "Pink"`.

Comment: @forpas I did not fully understand the issue (hence the question) so that's what I experienced. Looking back it is indeed wrong to compare those columns with each other :)

Comment: @sneaker so check if you have space on the end of your 'Pink', because LIKE is not a solution, rather workaround. Where should work.

Comment: @Kadet I failed to mention the titles are multiple words in some cases. If i'm not mistaken LIKE will be the solution in this case because I can't just remove spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query may not work because the "*Title*" field may have "hidden" spaces in its values.

If you want to ensure that you always get your matching strings, you should use the [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html) operator.

```
SELECT * 
FROM storename_history 
WHERE title LIKE "%Pink%"
```

If you want to investigate more on spaces, you can check the length of your string by using the [`CHAR_LENGTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) function.

Comment: Don't edit your post to include the answer, as for complex problems answers may be very long. If you want to point out the answer that worked for you, you should mark it as the answer of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer.

Comment: if it is just a matter of hidden spaces/unexpected characters, better they figure out what exactly to look for (or fix the data).  LIKE is overkill and likely (pun intended) to include results they don't want in some cases.

Comment: If their title is always made up of one word, they should strip characters. My assumption in this solution is that a title may be composed by many words. Doing this kind of operation in SQL carries all the troubles that affect natural language processing with it: `LIKE` seemed to be a good compromise for me.  @ysth

Comment: @LEMON At that point in time I could not mark your answer as the right answer yet. I did so now.

Comment: @ysth I did not mention it but most of the rows have multiple words in the title column ( for example: pink apple )

In this case i'd want to be able to search on pink , apple or pink apple.
 I NEED to use LIKE for that right?

Comment: How would you approach the problem? @ysth (is there a more efficient way that went unnoticed to me?)

Comment: I would want to better understand the problem before proposing any solution.  if they are looking for words in a column, for instance, do they want a search for pink to find pinkerton?  a search for apple to find apples?  a search for "small apples" to find "small pink apples"?